# position the form to the far right Windows.Forms

Tags: powershell, forms

code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Busca Email'
$form.ClientSize = ‘350,180’
$form.StartPosition = "manual"
$form.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(1000,0)
$form.AutoSize = $true

$form.ShowDialog()
```

with 0 it hits me at the top and if I put (0,0) it hits me on the left as I do so that it hits me on the right at all so I don't have to put (1000,0) the exact horizontal axis? e tested with (-1,0)

Comment: Your words confuse me.  Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish and remove terms like "hits me".  One thing I *can* suggest is to use VS and C# to get your form code nailed down.. then move the information over to powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will start the window on the far right hand side. The `top` value can be changed to move it up or down on the side. You do not need `$form.Location`

In this example, we are essentially setting an (X,Y) value automatically using the total screen width and subtracting it from the form width. Assuming a 1080p monitor is being used (1920x1080) that is 1920 - 350 = `1570`. It sets `X` to `1570` and then `Y` is the `Top` value of `0` for a final coordinate window start position (this value is the top left hand corner of the form) of `1570,0`. This guarantees the form is snug to the right side of the screen.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$monitor = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen

[void]::$monitor.WorkingArea.Width

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Busca Email'
$form.ClientSize = ‘350,180’
$form.StartPosition = "manual"
$form.Left = $monitor.WorkingArea.Width - $form.Width
$form.Top = 0
#$form.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(1000,0)
$form.AutoSize = $true


$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Good answer, but FYI, this line ***[void]::$monitor.WorkingArea.Width***, does not always work in all monitor setups. For example on my main dev box (4 monitors, different sizes), this would throw ***The property 'Screen[Bounds={X=0,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1080} WorkingArea={X=0,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1019} Primary=True DeviceName=\\.\DISPLAY9' cannot be 
found on this object. Verify that the property exists.*** It works as expected on my normal client (laptop).  So, some additional tweak/expectation is warranted.